# Ошибка при парсинге на bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Код:

```html
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.rbc.ru/politics/"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

title = soup.find_all(class_="item__title rm-cm-item-text js-rm-central-column-item-text").text()

print(title)
```

Это ошибка:

````py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\markm\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\News\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    title = soup.find_all(class_="item__title rm-cm-item-text js-rm-central-column-item-text").text()
  File "C:\Users\markm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2428, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?```
````

Comment: title = soup.find(class_="news-feed__item__title news-feed__item_in-main").text.strip()

Comment: первый поиск вернул None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно было пройти циклом по всем 'названиям'.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.rbc.ru/politics/"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

titles = soup.find("div", class_="l-row js-load-container").find_all(class_="item__title rm-cm-item-text js-rm-central-column-item-text")
for title in titles:
    print(title.text.strip())
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное)

Comment: Если помогло пометите ответ как правильный